# Is there a way to conditionally format cells if they are linked to by a formula in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

On sheet one, I have descriptions in column A, and values in column B. On sheet two, I have formulas in columns A through F that I manually fill in with values from sheet one column B based on what the description in column A is. I want to highlight cells in sheet one column B if the cell in question has already been used in a formula on sheet two. Using conditional formatting if possible, using a macro otherwise.

I want to be able to quickly see if a cell in column B has already been added to a formula on another sheet so that I do not accidentally include the value twice.

```
  Sheet One               Sheet Two
     A     B     C           A     B     C
1  salt    3            1       =B1+B4
2  base    3            2
3  base    4            3
4  salt    1            4             =B2+B3
5  base    4            5
```

I expect to be able to automatically highlight a cell that is already in another function without having to manually do it to reduce the error chance. In the example above cells B1 through B4 would be highlighted since they have been used in a formula while B5 would remain normal since it has not been used yet

Comment: What spreadsheet application are you using? (from review).

Comment: I would prefer google sheets so that I can add line items as I go about my day, but I can just make notes and enter into an excel sheet at the end of each day. Thats what I am doing currently with the code below.

Comment: Considering that you are using the VBA answer then [tag:google-sheets] should be removed and if you would like a solution for Google Sheets, you should post a new question. This because each applications use different programming languages and several spreadsheet functions do not work in the same way.

Comment: I understand they each use different languages. My thought with leaving the tag is that it keeps the answers less fragmented if the google-sheets method gets answered. Allowing someone else to see both and pick between them. I understand if it just makes the search function less effective though since no one has answered with a google-sheets answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## VBA Conditional Formatting feat. Array and Range Union

### Features

- [Find Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5DFind+Method))
- Cells Property
- Parent Property
- Formula Property
- Resize Method
- InStr Function
- Replace Function
- Union Method

### The Code

```
Sub CompareColumnWithRange()

  Const cStrTgtWs As Variant = 1        ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cStrSrcWs As Variant = 2        ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cLngTgtFirst As Long = 1        ' Target First Row
  Const cLngSrcFirst As Long = 1        ' Source First Row
  Const cStrTgtColumn As Variant = "B"  ' Target Column Letter/Number
  Const cStrSrcRange As String = "A:F"  ' Source Columns Range
  Const cColor As Long = 255            ' Formatting Color

  Dim rngTgt As Range                   ' Target Range
  Dim rngU As Range                     ' Target Union Range
  Dim vntSrc As Variant                 ' Source Array
  Dim i As Long                         ' Source Array Row Counter
  Dim j As Integer                      ' Source Array Column Counter
  Dim k As Long                         ' Target Range Row Counter

  With Worksheets(cStrSrcWs).Range(cStrSrcRange)
    ' Check if sheet is empty (No data).
    If .Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), -4123, , 1) _
        Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Paste Source Range's formulas into Source Array. Since the previous
    ' With statement refers to a range, the Parent property has to be used
    ' to 'aquire sheet level'.
    vntSrc = .Parent.Range(.Parent.Cells(cLngSrcFirst, .Column), _
        .Parent.Cells(.Cells.Find("*", , , , , 2).Row, _
        .Columns.Count - .Column + 1)).Formula
  End With

'  ' Print contents of vntSrc to Immediate window.
'  For i = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
'    For j = 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2)
'      Debug.Print vntSrc(i, j)
'    Next
'  Next

  ' Target Column vs Source Array
  With Worksheets(cStrTgtWs)
    ' Determine the Target Range (1 column).
    Set rngTgt = .Cells(cLngTgtFirst, cStrTgtColumn).Resize( _
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, cStrTgtColumn).End(xlUp).Row - cLngTgtFirst + 1)
    ' Loop through Target Range (1 column)
    For k = cLngTgtFirst To .Cells(.Rows.Count, cStrTgtColumn).End(xlUp).Row
      ' Loop through Source Array rows.
      For i = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
        ' Loop through Source Array columns.
        For j = 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2)
          ' Search for Target Range's cell address in current value
          ' of Source Array i.e. remove the $ signs in both, and add
          ' sheet name for Target Range.
          If InStr(1, Replace(vntSrc(i, j), "$", ""), .Name & "!" _
              & Replace(.Cells(k, cStrTgtColumn).Address, "$", "")) <> 0 Then
            If Not rngU Is Nothing Then ' Add cells to existing range.
              Set rngU = Union(rngU, .Cells(k, cStrTgtColumn))
             Else ' Add cells to non-existing range. Runs only the first time.
              Set rngU = .Cells(k, cStrTgtColumn)
            End If
            Exit For  ' If a value has been found, stop searching for more.
          End If
        Next
      Next
    Next
  End With

  ' Apply formatting to all 'collected' cells in Target Union Range in one go.
  If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
    rngU.Interior.Color = cColor
    Set rngU = Nothing
  End If

  Set rngTgt = Nothing

End Sub
```